# In which conditions a weighted sum is comparable to an unweighted one?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Consider $(a_n)_n$ and $(w_n)_n$ two sequences of non-negative numbers, with $w_n \geq 1 \forall n $ and $w_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$. I'd like to know what we must assume about the sequences such that the following is true:

There's a constant $C$ such that, for all $N>0$
$$\sum_{n=1}^N a_n w_n \leq C \sum_{n=1}^N a_n$$

Or, in other words,

$$\limsup_{N \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{n=1}^N a_n w_n}{\sum_{n=1}^N a_n}<\infty.$$

Notice that, as $w_n \geq 1$, the sequence $\frac{\sum_{n=1}^N a_n w_n}{\sum_{n=1}^N a_n}$ is increasing, and therefore if the $\limsup$ is finite, then the limit exists.

---

This is true if both $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n w_n$ are convergent series.

For example take $a_n = \frac{1}{n^3}$ and $w_n = n$.

If however $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nw_n=\infty$ but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$, then the result is false.

For example take $a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$ and $w_n = n$.

---

But what may happen if both series are divergent? I saw in this post [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92945/is-there-a-discrete-version-of-de-lhôpitals-rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92945/is-there-a-discrete-version-of-de-lh%C3%B4pitals-rule) this Stolz-Cesàro theorem (I didn't know previously), stating that

> If $b_n$ and $c_n$ are both increasing and unbounded, then
> $$\lim \frac{b_n}{c_n} = \lim \frac{b_{n+1}-b_n}{c_{n+1}-c_n}$$

and in that case, making $b_n = \sum_{j=1}^n a_jw_j$ and $c_n = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j$, then

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b_n}{c_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} w_{n+1} = \infty.$$

So the only instance in which such sums are comparable is if both of them are convergent? Is this correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any $C$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^N a_n w_n \leq C \sum_{n=1}^N a_n
$ where $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$ and $w_n=n$ ?

Comment: No, there isn't. That's precisely the example I gave for conditions in which that result is false. The left-hand-side of the inequality is infinite. the right hand side is finite.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N a_n=L \in R$

$\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N a_n=L \in R \Rightarrow \lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N Ca_n=\lim_{N \to \infty}C\sum_{n=0}^{N}a_n=CL \in R$

$\sum_{n=1}^N a_n w_n \leq C \sum_{n=1}^N a_n
 \Rightarrow \lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^Na_nw_n \in R$ (According to comparison theorem)